How can I manually trigger timing jdbc input in logstash?
I have one timing jdbc logstash input and load data into elasticsearch.
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "XXX"
        jdbc_user => "XXX"
        jdbc_password => "XXX"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "XXX"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        statement => "XXX"
        schedule => "0 3 * * * America/New_York"
        type => "XXX"
        add_field => { "[@metadata][indexname]" => "XXX" }
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts=> ["XXX","XXX","XXX"]
        index=>"%{[@metadata][indexname]}"
        user => XXX
        password => XXX
        ssl => true
        ssl_certificate_verification => false
        cacert => 'XXX'
        document_id => "%{uniqueid}"
    }
    stdout {}
}

I wonder how can I manually trigger it running, if there have some jdbc connection failed or elasticsearch connection issue?

You can run the logstash on command line like the following.
bin/logstash -f mypipeline.conf

Because you have stdout you will also see the output on the terminal.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash-command-line.html
Note: if it's slow don't worry the stdout is a performance killer :) Recommended to remove it on prod after testing.
Note2: Remove schedule in logstash.conf during test otherwise you should wait until the schedule time.

thanks for your advice and comments, but my question is, my logstash is timing, can't remove "schedule", then how can I trigger it like force run it, if latest scheduled running is not success

You're welcome Jason. Thanks for clarification. There is no logic for retry_failed but maybe increasing connection_retry_attempts (default 1) can help.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html

Addition to that, you can create some logic in elasticsearch to find out logstash schedule didn't worked and retrigger again. Eg. check the @timestamp if it's older than 6 hours trigger manually. You can do that with a shell script or a python code

The best you can do is to put monitoring on Logstash. From monitoring data you can setup different types of alert like

Number of events processed. If number is less than expectation it will generate alert and you can simply refer log file what wrong.
You can read logstash error log and push to Elasticsearch using Elastic agent. In that log, logstash will log error if something comes like db connection etc. You can write alert rule for that also.
Monitoring agent remains active even if the Logstash instance does not. So if your logtsash stopped, you will able to catch in logs and it could be the another alert.

